# Firebase Queries Not Firing in Order that they were called

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, loops, firebase

I'm calling Firebase queries inside a `for` loop. However, the Firebase queries aren't firing in the order that they're called. Here's the code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.orderedKeys.description);

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.orderedKeys.count; i++) {
        [[selectedLanguageRef childByAppendingPath:self.orderedKeys[i]] observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *userSnapshot) {             
            NSLog(@"%@", self.orderedKeys.description);
            NSLog(@"%@", userSnapshot.key);
        }];
}
```

In this code, the NSLog returns this for `self.orderedKeys.description`:

fakeUser8, fakeUser7,
"facebook:10205598530457903", fakeUser3, fakeUser10, fakeUser9, fakeUser14, fakeUser13

But the NSLog for `userSnapshot.key` will always fire in this order:

fakeUser3, fakeUser10, facebook:10205598530457903, fakeUser8, fakeUser7, fakeUser14, fakeUser13, fakeUser9

What's going on here? How do I get the queries to fire in the same order that they're called?

Comment: NO! Don't do this! Firebase works asynchronously and you should wait for the results from one action before taking the next action. We can provide some direction but need to know what your expected result is and also a snippet of your Firebase structure (as text please, Firebase Dashboard->Export). And if you have to perform a series of queries, there may be an issue with the structure that causing you to have to do that.

Comment: @Jay could you clarify what exactly am I not supposed to be doing? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous and your code may be overwriting returned values or the values may be returning in an unexpected order due to lag. So say for example your first query fires and there's a delay returning that, but the second query returns the data faster. The returned data is not synchronous like your code is so you need to deal with the returned data before moving on. Multiple queries like that can probably (should) be avoided so post your structure and intent and let's have a look.

Comment: @Jay thanks for offering to help me restructure. If I have to restructure, I'll figure it out on my own. I was hoping there was a quick fix, or a way to get data back from Firebase in the order that it was called, but if there isn't then I'll see what I can do. Has anyone asked about this before? What do people generally do instead of looping through long lists of calls?

Comment: That's a super good question; in general, Firebase needs to be structured in the way you are going to use it; pre-planning for queries, breaking out nodes that will be observed, denormalizing data, accounting for it's asynchronous nature as well as planning for rules is something that kinda needs to be done up front. Trust me I've JSON'd myself into a corner many times and had to restructure my data to make it work.

Comment: @Jay can you put what you just said as the answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is asynchronous and your code may be overwriting returned values or the values may be returning in an unexpected order due to lag.

Say for example your first query fires and there's a delay returning that, but the second query returns the data faster. The returned data is not synchronous like code is so you need to deal with the returned data before moving on.

In general, Firebase needs to be structured in the way you are going to use it; pre-planning for queries, breaking out nodes that will be observed, denormalizing data, accounting for it's asynchronous nature as well as planning for rules is something that needs to be done up front.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Firebase specifically but it seems like a problem with running multiple asynchronous calls at the same time. You could use a serial queue to ensure only one runs at a time.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6